# Save Mat image from camera prosilica

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am developping a program to acquire image from prosilica camera.

I recuperate the frame as a strcut that contains a ImageBuffer variable.

To save recuperated image, I do like this:

```
tPvFrame frame;// a struct given by the SDK camera. 
Mat Image=Mat(frame->Height, frame->Width, CV_32FC3, frame->ImageBuffer); 
//the image depth is 5.
cout<<"Depth Image---------------------------"<<Image.depth()<<endl;
//The program has unexpectedly finished here 
imwrite("image.jpg", Image);
```

What is the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

`Mat` image depth is 3 if you use `CV_32FC3`. Then you can't create the `Mat` image, and when you try to write that image it crashes.